# Conteo de caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un problema con este ejercicio, debo ingresar mi eleccion de un menu de restaurante solo ingresando la inicial en mayuscula de lo que vaya a seleccionar, el porgrama debe leer lo que se ingresa, contar la cantidad de lo seleccionado incluyendo cuantas veces se selecciono, al final debe imprimir la cantidad de lo que se pidio y la inicial de cada cosa que se pidio, y si se repite solo debe imprimir una vez la letra, el problema es que no logro que los resultados salgan en el orden que se ingreso

```
print("Menu")
print("Menu \nhola \nArroz \nBerenjena \nEnsalada de la casa \nFríjoles \nGarbanzos \nHabichuelas asadas \nLentejas \nPollo \nRatatouille \nSpaghetti \nZanahorias en julianas")
print ("\ningrese su pedido: ")
cadena1 = input(" ")
cadena2 = ""
salida = ""

if cadena1.count("A") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("A"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "A"
if cadena1.count("B") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("B"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "B"
if cadena1.count("E") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("E"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "E"
if cadena1.count("F") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("F"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "F"
if cadena1.count("G") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("G"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "G"
if cadena1.count("H") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("H"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "H"
if cadena1.count("L") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("L"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "L"
if cadena1.count("P") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("P"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "P"
if cadena1.count("R") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("R"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "R"
if cadena1.count("S") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("S"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "S"
if cadena1.count("Z") > 0:
    conteo = str(cadena1.count("Z"))
    salida += conteo
    cadena2 += "Z"
    
    
    
#print(cadena1.split(sep='\s'))
for letra in cadena2:
    print(letra, end=" ")

for letra in salida:
    print(letra, end=" ")
```

Comment: Otro vez con la misma pregunta.

Comment: @CandidMoe nop, no es la misma

Comment: @Christian. Recibe un pedido de la forma "AABEE" ; luego imprime "A B E 2 1 2". Lo que pide se soluciona con la pregunta señalada.